# Cannot Access Tomcat Server from external server

Tags: networking, iptables, tomcat, ufw

I have found several people with this problem, tried many solutions, but none have worked for me.

I have recently setup a new VPS at a hosting company, linux with Centos9.

I've installed and run Tomcat, and the admin tool, successfully, and verified they are running locally, both through http://localhost and http://ipaddress

If I try to connect from my home pc using the ip address on chrome, it says it "took too long to respond"

So I googled far and wide and have so far done the following (restarting tomcat each time)

- Changed "address=" in my connector to "address=0.0.0.0"
- Changed to port 80 (catalina log said tomcat didn't have permissions, fail)
- Changed to port 8081 (same problem)
- Installed and enabled ufw and allowed ports (8081 and 8080)... same problem
- Added useIPVHosts="true"/ to my Connector in server.xml

netstat:

```
[root@vultr localhost]# netstat -lntu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::8081                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*
```

Thank you

[edit] here is the output from the iptables command

```
 iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ufw-user-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc
ufw-not-local  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-user-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-user-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh /* 'dapp_SSH' */
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             mdns.mcast.net       udp dpt:mdns /* 'dapp_mDNS' */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:webcache
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:webcache
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:tproxy
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:tproxy

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: A timeout usually indicates a firewall issue. Check your `iptables -L` directly (not via ufw) and check with your hoster if they have a firewall in place.

Comment: edit the question instead of using the commentary section, thanks

Comment: okay thanks i have put the output from the iptables command into the question

Comment: SOLUTION:  I had installed and enabled ufw, without knowing that firewalld runs by default.  By disabling the second firewall (firewalld), it worked